# Prime Number Checker Written in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, primes

I have given up on the number generator because I understand that it was, in fact, dividing every number until it received a prime number. I have changed the code so that prime numbers from a specified range `"a" to "?" (in this case, 10)` in the `Prime_2` method are checked to be prime in the Prime method. Then the Prime method returns if that number is prime by setting a Boolean variable, prime, to true or false but so far I have only gotten a true for 2 and false for the rest. Which is obviously not true. Therefore, I would appreciate any assistance/comments/suggestions in making this new program workable.

```
public bool Prime(long num) // Prime method with a parameter for one number
{
    int div = 3; // what we divide by after checking if the number is divisible by 2
    bool prime = true; // set prime to true
    {
        for (long i = 0; i < 100 && prime == true; i++) // run 100 passes
        {
            if (num % 2 == 0 && num != 2) // if the number is divisible by 2 
            {                             // and is not 2, prime is false.
                prime = false;
            }
            else if (num % 2 != 0 && num != 2) // if the number is not divisible 
            {                                  // by 2 and the number is not 2...
                for (long x = 0; x <= 1000; x++) // then run 1000 passes of this:
                {
                    if (num % Math.Pow((div), x) == 0 && num != Math.Pow((div), x))
                    {   // if the number is divisible by our div to the power of x 
                        // and the number is not equal to div to the power of x, 
                        // prime is false.
                        prime = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        else   // otherwise add 2 to div making it the next consecutive odd number 
            {  // and run the pass again
                div = div + 2;
            }

        }
        return prime;
    }
}
public void Prime_2() // void Prime_2 method
{
    long a = 2; // starting number 2
    long b = 0; // set b

    Program prg = new Program(); //new instance of the Program class
    while (a <= 10)//the range a (2) - 10
    {
        b = a;//set "b" to "a" every time
        prg.Prime(b); // run the Prime method for numbers 2-10
        Console.WriteLine(b); // write the number being checked
        Console.WriteLine(prg.Prime(b)); // return if it is true or false for prime
        a++; // add 1 to a
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program prog = new Program(); // instantiate a new Program
    prog.Prime_2(); // run the method, Prime_2
    Console.ReadLine(); // wait for input
}
```

Comment: You really should be using a `yield return`...

Comment: You are modifying the number inside your prime checking function. It looks like you are trying to find a prime number that is less than given number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to check each number from 2 to 100 for primality by trial division, which is what you seem to be trying to do, use this pseudocode algorithm:

```
function isPrime(n)
    if n % 2 == 0
        return n == 2
    d := 3
    while d * d <= n
        if n % d == 0
            return False
        d := d + 2
    return True
```

This takes time *O(n<sup>1.5</sup>)* for finding the primes up to *n*. If you want a faster algorithm, use the Sieve of Eratosthenes, which is *O(n log log n)*:

```
function primes(n)
    sieve := makeArray(2..n, True)
    for p from 2 to n step 1
        if sieve[p]
            output p
            for i from p*p to n step p
                sieve[i] := False
```

If you're interested in programming with prime numbers, I modestly recommend this [essay](http://programmingpraxis.com/essays) at my blog.

Comment: Actually, I should have attempted to use you program before editing mine. This is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: @Orren: Don't forget to follow the link. There are implementations of both `primes` and `isPrime` in several languages.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you are doing what you are doing in your function. Could you add some comments in your code? However a fast way to check for a prime number would be the following

```
bool IsPrime(int number) {
  if (number % 2 == 0 && number != 2) return false; // Don't check even numbers

  for (int i = 2; i < number; i++) {
    if (number % i == 0 && i != number) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Of course you should then call the function above within an if statement and if true then display the number.

Comment: To have a faster solution, you can modify your loop: int n = (int)(Math.Sqrt(number) + 1); for (int i = 3; i < n; i += 2)

Comment: He is not trying to check to see if the number is prime, he is trying to fix his code so the prime number are in sequence not randomly generated.